# css text background diffrent for space between text lines

Tags: html, css, text, formatting, background

I have some formatted text : [link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JKzeG/16/)
and i want to make it to look like this :

[image]

How can this be done?

Comment: You mean with the separating margin between lines? A tricky one, unless my brain doesn't work (likely). +1

Comment: Is the JSFiddle link correct ? seems odd.

Comment: the JS fiddle is what i arrived at when i tried to make what the Designer gave me to do ( the image)

Comment: You can certainly do this if they are two different pieces of text, if your designer is ok with it i.e.

Comment: yeah thought so too.. that text represents a short news title actually , in a twitter like news feed on a homepage, so it is one text entity that is within one database column, and its tricky thought u guys can cook something up `couse i`m stuck

Comment: Well my hack is kind of working...

Answer (score 1):

Here it is..

```css
.news_text{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:11px;
  width:220px;
  background-color:#866b62;
  color:#FFF;
  padding:3px;

  line-height: 1.2em;  /*notice line-height*/ 
  overflow: hidden;  /*to hide extra transform*/ 
}
.news_text::before{
 background:repeating-linear-gradient(transparent,transparent calc(1.2em - 1px),white calc(1.2em - 1px),white calc(1.2em + 0px)); /*that same line-height*/
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
 content: '';
 position:absolute;
 top:3px; /*same as padding*/
 bottom: 1em; /*use with care when handling padding*/
 left:0;
 right: 0;
}
.news_text::after{
 content:'------';  /*'' blank was not working on inline-block*/
 color:transparent; /*to hide '------'*/
 background-color: white; /*same as background*/ 
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 transform-origin: top left;
 transform:scale(20,2) scaleY(1.1); /*adjust based on your content*/
}
```

```html
<span id="news_text" class="news_text">
  Maecenas tempus rhoncus nisl, eu lorem blandit a consectetuer adipiscing
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur libero nobis, ut itaque, quibusdam, cumque corporis optio dignissimos consequatur voluptatum cum, provident officia
</span>
```

Don't know why I spent so much time on it....